# Pegar varios valores boolean e jogar dentro de uma variavel

Tags: java, android

Precisava pegar todas as respostas que estão dentro do boolean `respostas1` e jogar dentro de uma outra variável pra eu poder mandar para o banco MySQL.

Da maneira que eu fiz, ele esta me retornando tudo false.

Por exemplo, tenho 4 perguntas, ele deveria me trazer: true, false, true e false...

e esta retornando false false false.

***Porque ela esta retornando false e como solucionar?***

```
for (int x=0; x<respostas2.length; x++){
for (final String a : ids){
    idPERGUNTAS = a;

}

Log.i("ID da Perguntas", "IDS das Perguntas: "+idPERGUNTAS);
//parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ids", idPERGUNTAS));

for (String IDPaciente : idPacientes){
    for (int i=0; i < respostas2.length; i++){
        idPACIENTES = IDPaciente;

    }
}

Log.i("ID do Paciente", "IDS dos Pacientes: "+idPACIENTES);
//parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idNome", idPACIENTES));

for(boolean respostas1 : respostas2){
    RESPOSTAS = respostas1;

}

Log.i("Resposta", "Respostas: "+RESPOSTAS);
//parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("respostas", String.valueOf(RESPOSTAS)));
```

Eu tenho 3 valores que gostaria de mandar pra base de dados, pelo que eu entendi, so dessa maneira que eu conseguiria enviar todos... pq sao varias respostas...
Se eu colocar a resposta dentro do for, ele ira me retornar todas elas so que vai triplicar...

Comment: Você poderia mostrar como você preenche os valores no seu array `respostas2`? A propósito, não entendi muito bem qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: Já editei la @Math

Comment: Acredito que seu problema de estar retornando tudo false está ocorrendo na hora de passar os valores de uma activity para outra, não?

Comment: O duro que não, eu ja fiz o teste.
eu coloquei um Log dentro do for e ele me retorna tudo certo, mas eu precisava pegar os valores fora do for, mais ai que eu estou tendo esse problema de tudo false

Comment: esse respostas é um array?
pq se não vc ta atribuindo um em cima do outro

Comment: o RESPOSTAS é um boolean...

Comment: se você tirar do comentário o Log.i que tá dentro do for, e comentar o Log.i que tá fora, não funciona?

Comment: Você esta usando um for para pegar elemento a elemento de um array e colocar dentro de uma variável booleana, a variável só guarda um valor, ou seja a cada loop do for você joga fora a variável anterior guardada e atribui uma nova no mesmo lugar ela sobrepõe o valor.

Comment: Funciona sim, mas eu precisava pegar esses valores fora do for, se não da erro...
@Joannis, vc esta certo, ele esta pegando sempre a ultima resposta... Esta atribuindo em cima do outro.. =(

Comment: precisa fora do for?
posta como vc esta lendo essa variavel
a parte que vc esta add os parametros

Comment: Porque fora do for?
joga o for para onde você atribui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta usando um `for` para pegar elemento a elemento de um array e colocar dentro de uma variável booleana. A variável só guarda um valor, ou seja a cada loop do `for` você joga fora a variável anterior guardada e atribui uma nova no mesmo lugar ela sobrepõe o valor.

Tenta isto:

```
//------------------------------ENVIAR DADOS PARA O BANCO--------------------------

try{

    String urlPost2 = "http://"+l.IP+"/projetotcc/android/respostas.php";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String idPERGUNTAS = null;
    String idPACIENTES = null;
    boolean RESPOSTAS = false;
    //int intResposta = 0;

  //  
        for (final String a : ids){
            idPERGUNTAS = a;
            Log.i("ID da Perguntas", "IDS das Perguntas: "+idPERGUNTAS);
            parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ids", idPERGUNTAS));
        }

        for (String IDPaciente : idPacientes){
            for (int i=0; i < respostas2.length; i++){
                idPACIENTES = IDPaciente;
                Log.i("ID do Paciente", "IDS dos Pacientes: "+idPACIENTES);
                parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idNome", idPACIENTES));
            }
        }

        for(boolean respostas1 : respostas2){
             RESPOSTAS = respostas1;
             Log.i("ID da Resposta", "IDS das Respostas: "+RESPOSTAS);
             parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("respostas", String.valueOf(RESPOSTAS)));
        }

//-----------------------------------FIM - ENVIAR DADOS----------------------------------------
        for (int x=0; x<respostas2.length; x++){
        String respostaRetornada2 = null;

        try{
            respostaRetornada2 = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost2, parametrosPost2);
            Log.i("Entrou", "Entrou");
            String resposta2 = respostaRetornada2.toString();
            resposta2 = resposta2.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            Log.i("Logar", "Resposta: "+resposta2);

            if (resposta.equals("1")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Respostas gravadas com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro ao gravar respostas!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch(Exception erro){
            f.mensagemSimples(Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques.this, "Erro", "Erro: "+erro);
        }
    //}

}
```

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2217/fechamento-de-uma-pergunta-indevida-ou-n%C3%A3o